# angular4 ERROR Error: No provider for NetworkService

Tags: angular

first time creating angular4 project. i add network.service.ts to services.module.ts providers, then i add services.module.ts to shared.module.ts providers and then i add shared.module.ts to app.module.ts providers. 
when i try to use NetworkService in my view i get ERROR Error: No provider for NetworkService.

when i add NetworkService straight to the app.module.ts providers this error dosen't occur.

i would like to know if it's possible to chain the providers like i did and if so how to do it currently.

network.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class NetworkService {

  constructor() { }

  test = "testing";

  myTest(){
    return 'method testing';
  }

}
```

service.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NetworkService } from './network.service';


@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports:[],
  declarations: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [NetworkService]
})

export class ServicesModule {
}
```

shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesModule } from './services/services.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports:[],
  declarations: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [
    ServicesModule,
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule }     from '@angular/router';

import { SharedModule }     from './shared/shared.module';

import { AppComponent }     from './app.component';

import { ROUTES } from './app.route';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [
    SharedModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of `ServiceModule` is fine, however, you need to import the module in other feature modules instead of providing them:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesModule } from './services/services.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ServicesModule], // import modules
  exports:[],
  declarations: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [] // do not provide modules
})

export class SharedModule {
}
```

Same goes for your AppModule. There is no need to put your services into the `exports: []` of a module, it is only meant for directives, pipes and other modules (with components being a sub-form of directives).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a provider in your appmodule

The provider have to be add at the providers line with SharedModule

Comment: what about the SharedModule inside the providers inside app.module.ts?

Comment: I am trying to find an example for you

Comment: You have to add NetworkService to your providers in app module